# Checking user details on login Android

Tags: android, http, authentication, android-asynctask, httprequest

I'm trying to make a login system for my application. Currently the user can create an account online and download the app. They are then prompted for their username and password.

When they press the login button I want to make a request to a php script on the server to check the results and return true if the user does exist and false if they do not exist.

I am a little bit confused about how I should implement this?

I am trying to create a seperate class that extends `AsyncTask`.

This is my MainActivity

```
EditText username;
EditText password;
Button loginBtn;
LinearLayout loginform;
String passwordDetail;
String usernameDetail;
String url = "http://www.jdiadt.com/example/checklogindetails.php";

HttpTask httptask;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Hide the Action Bar
    ActionBar ab;
    ab = this.getActionBar();
    ab.hide();

    //Get references to XML
    username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    loginBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
    loginform = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.loginform);

    //Animation
    final AlphaAnimation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f , 1.0f ); 
    AlphaAnimation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation( 1.0f , 0.0f ) ; 
    fadeIn.setDuration(1200);
    fadeIn.setFillAfter(true);
    fadeOut.setDuration(1200);
    fadeOut.setFillAfter(true);
    fadeOut.setStartOffset(4200+fadeIn.getStartOffset());

    //Run thread after 2 seconds to start Animation
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){

        public void run() {
            //display login form
            loginform.startAnimation(fadeIn);
            loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //display();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Checking login details...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if(checkLoginDetails()){
                        //OPENS NEW ACTIVITY
                        //Close splash screen
                        finish();
                        //start home screen 
                        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), SectionsActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        //creates fade in animation between two activities
                        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.splash_fade_out);
                    }
                    else{
                    }
                }
            });

        }

    }, 2000);


}

//Check the login details before proceeding.
public boolean checkLoginDetails(){
    usernameDetail = username.getText().toString();
    passwordDetail = password.getText().toString();
    httptask = new HttpTask();
    httptask.execute(url, usernameDetail, passwordDetail);
    //if exists return true
    //else return false
    return false;
}
```

}

This is my HttpTask

```
public class HttpTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

    String url = params[0];
    String username = params[1];
    String password = params[2];

    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

    List <NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

    try {
        httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        return true;
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

This is my php script on  my webserver `checklogindetails.php`

```
    require_once 'db_connect.php';

    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    $pwdMD5 = md5($password);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password='$pwdMD5'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($count == 1){
        echo "Log in successful";
//RETURN TRUE
    }
    else{
        echo "Wrong username or password";
//RETURN FALSE
    }
```

I guess the place I'm most confused about is how to constuct the php script to check the login details and how I can decide what to do based on it returning true or false.

I'd appreciate any advice or help on this subject! Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

The above code looks good except that you are missing the last step.
Returning something from the PHP and then reading it in the app.

I would suggest changing the output of the PHP to something easier to parse/maintain like "OK" and "ERROR"

Then add the following code to the HttpTask.

```
final HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
if (response != null)
{
    // parse response
    final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    if (entity == null)
    {
        // response is empty, this seems an error in your use case
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
        {
            Log.d(HttpClient.TAG, "Response has no body"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            // convert response to string
            this.mResponseAsString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            {
                Log.d(HttpClient.TAG, "Response: " + this.mResponseAsString); //$NON-NLS-1$
            }

            // parse the string (assuming OK and ERROR as possible responses)
            if (this.mResponseAsString != null && this.mResponseAsString.equals("OK")
            {
                // add happy path code here
            }
            else
            {
                // add sad path here
            }
        }
        catch (final ParseException e)
        {
            Log.e(HttpClient.TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        catch (final IOException e)
        {
            Log.e(HttpClient.TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
    this.mResponseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
}
```

Personally I would also refactor the "OK" in the HttpTask to a constant (for easy reading and maintaining) and also refactor most the HTTP based code to some kind of base class or utility class so you can reuse it.